# Resources about Busacker & Gowen algorithm

Tags: optimization, algorithms, network-flow, literature-research, online-resources

I have a relatively hard time understanding the Busacker & Gowen algorithm. I could not
find any resources on it, contrary to Ford-Fulkerson method that is described in Comen's "Introduction to algorithms" book.

The only resource about it that I found was [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZXwIgE-ne8) that is in French but at least it shows an example of using the method.

Are there any other resources on the method like the one I mentioned?

**EDIT:** Is Busacker & Gowen algorithm the same as Successive Shortest Path Algorithm?

Comment: Perhaps I will have a better time, or not, reading the their tech report https://ntrl.ntis.gov/NTRL/dashboard/searchResults/titleDetail/AD249662.xhtml.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade Thanks for the hint. However, It's really hard to get the hang of how the method work when the are no visual examples of it :/